# SingleConnectionyFactory with DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring-jms

I need some help with the below code. Is it fine to use `SingleConnectionFactory` when using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` as mentioned below? I am having problem with QM channel disconnecting due to reaching max connection per client.

```java
JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> createJmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory cf,DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, new SingleConnectionFactory(cf));
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setConcurrency("15-50");
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(2);
    factory.setBackOff(new FixedBackOff());
    return factory; 
}
```

Here is how my `JmsListener` uses it:

```java
    @Bean(name = "containerFactory")
    public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) throws NamingException {
        //call to createJmsListenerContainerFactory()
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "queue1", containerFactory = "containerFactory", concurrency = "16-32")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes; but the SCF should be configured as a `@Bean` (not `new ...` there) so that Spring can manage its lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks Gary. WIll it impact the performance of my application?

Comment: I would not expect it to, unless you have really high volumes - all will go over the same connection.

Comment: My application is dealing with high volumes of messages. Will it be good idea to use CachingConnectionFactory keeping cache consumer and producer property to 'false'?

Comment: No; you must not cache consumers with variable concurrency; you can end up with idle consumers in the cache and the broker doesn't know they are idle; the single container is best. Container consumers are long-running anyway, so no need to cache. It's best to test the performance profile with and without using a single connection to determine the impact in your particular environment. The caching factory with caching disabled is effectively the same as the single factory.